# How to approach a group project in Tableau when having multiple csv files in a folder

Tags: tableau-api, project

I'm new to working with data. Our Tableau class recently assigned me and my group a project where we chose the 'Airline Customer Holiday Booking Dataset'. We aim to present our analysis based on this dataset, which comprises four CSV files (after unzipping):

- Airline Review
- Customer Comment
- Passenger booking data
- Survey data inflight satisfaction score

Here are the questions we plan to address in our presentation:

1. Identifying factors influencing successful holiday bookings and improving conversion rates.
2. Evaluating the impact of different services (e.g., in-flight meals, extra baggage allowance) on customers' booking decisions.
3. Assessing the relationship between booking lead time and customer choices.
4. Analyzing the popularity of various routes and flight schedules.
5. Investigating the influence of booking channels on customer behavior.
6. Predicting the likelihood of a successful holiday booking based on customer characteristics.

Our team has decided to divide the cleaning process among us. For instance, I will handle question 2 by cleaning the Survey and Booking files, while another teammate will manage the customer comment dataset.

Regarding our approach to cleaning the dataset, I initially thought about merging all the files and cleaning them together. This would prevent potential issues arising from merging separately cleaned datasets later on.

What do you suggest we do in this scenario? Could you recommend an optimal way to clean the data?

Thank you!

I am trying to merge the four csv files in Python. and def using the code via Chatgpt.